# KendoWindow will only open once when called from Kendo ToolBar button

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have looked around at a few links on SO and outside of SO and have seen alot of this type of question, but nothing in the way of why this happens on a toolbar button.

Here is a dojo of it..

[here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Cwm/okEZe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by targeting the window with the kendo data attribute and using the open function:

```
function ImClicked(e) {
    //alert(e.target.text() + " is clicked");

   var item = $("#showMyWindow"),
        wnd = item.data("kendoWindow");

    item.kendoWindow({
        width: "505px",
        height: "315px",
        title: "Hey I'm a Title",
        content: "Howdy, I'm a winda",
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        close: function (e) {
            $("#showMyWindow").empty();
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow").center();
      wnd.open();
};
```

[Updated dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UHaTA/2)

Found this solution in this Telerik forum post:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/window-only-opens-once

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated.